# Последовательный выбор select с поиском

Tags: javascript, html

У меня мало опыта и знаний, поставили задачу, нужно срочно сделать.
Нужно сделать последовательный выбор: район, потом город/посёлок (Из этого района). Плюс хочу что бы работал поиск, по отдельности получается - но при объёдинении второй select ломается.

```js
toggleSel.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (toggleSel.value == 'р1') {
    result.innerHTML = '';
    let rusCity = ['---', 'г. 1111111111111111', 'г. 2)', '1', 'с. 3', 'с. 4', 'с. 5'];
    for (let i = 0; i < rusCity.length; i++) {
      let options = new Option(rusCity[i]);
      result.appendChild(options);
    }
    result.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }
  if (toggleSel.value == 'р2') {
    result.innerHTML = '';
    let usCity = ['---', 'г. 1', 'с. 2', 'с. 1', 'с. 3', 'с. 4', 'с. 5', 'с. 6', 'с. 7'];
    for (let i = 0; i < usCity.length; i++) {
      let options = new Option(usCity[i]);
      result.appendChild(options);
    }
    result.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }
  if (toggleSel.value == 'р3') {
    result.innerHTML = '';
    let cnCity = ['---', 'с 12323234', 'с. 2', 'с. 3'];
    for (let i = 0; i < cnCity.length; i++) {
      let options = new Option(cnCity[i]);
      result.appendChild(options);
    }
    result.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }

  if (toggleSel.value == '---') {
    for (let i = 1; i < result.options.length; i++) {
      result.options[i].outerHTML = ''
    }
    result.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>qq3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Выберите Ваш район</h1>

  <select class="sel-group" id="toggleSel">
    <option>---</option>
    <option>р1</option>
    <option>р2</option>
    <option>р3</option>
  </select>



  <h1>Выберите Ваш город/посёлок</h1>

  <select class="sel-group" id="result" disabled="disabled">
    <option>---</option>
  </select>
  <script src='https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/aKbRrO.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Добавляю следующее и , первый select работает, второй  ломается, ещё заметил что если заккоментировать то что добавил - перестаёт работать всё равно.. и не в кэше дело, проверял

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.min.css">
<script src='https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/aKbRrO.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".sel-group").chosen();
</script>
```

Посоветуйте, мб по другому как-то лучше сделать, или мб я не заметил что-то. Ещё почему-то, после того как

Comment: Почему-то тут выдает ошибку при выполнении кода, но если на компе запустить то норм

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Oleja322: уточните, о каком поиске речь и что делать с результатами выбора/поиска.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего конкретного про вывод результата и поиск(?) в вопросе не сказано, поэтому пока только оптимизировал код:

```js
const aData = {
  р1: ['---', 'г. 1111111111111111', 'г. 2)', '1', 'с. 3', 'с. 4', 'с. 5'],
  р2: ['---', 'г. 1', 'с. 2', 'с. 1', 'с. 3', 'с. 4', 'с. 5', 'с. 6', 'с. 7'],
  р3: ['---', 'с 12323234', 'с. 2', 'с. 3']
};
toggleSel.addEventListener('change', function() {
  result.innerHTML = '';
  if (toggleSel.value !== '---') {
    aData[toggleSel.value].forEach(el => {
      let options = new Option(el);
      result.appendChild(options);
    });
    result.removeAttribute('disabled')
  } else {
    result.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Выберите Ваш район</h1>
<select class="sel-group" id="toggleSel">
  <option>---</option>
  <option>р1</option>
  <option>р2</option>
  <option>р3</option>
</select>

<h1>Выберите Ваш город/посёлок</h1>
<select class="sel-group" id="result" disabled="disabled"></select>
```

Почти целый плагин для стилизации селекта получился:

```js
const aData = {
  р1: ["---", "г. 1111111111111111", "г. 2)", "1", "с. 3", "с. 4", "с. 5"],
  р2: ["---", "г. 1", "с. 2", "с. 1", "с. 3", "с. 4", "с. 5", "с. 6", "с. 7"],
  р3: ["---", "с 12323234", "с. 2", "с. 3"]
};

toggleSel.addEventListener("change", function() {
  result.innerHTML = "";
  if (toggleSel.value !== "---") {
    aData[toggleSel.value].forEach((el) => result.appendChild(new Option(el)));
    result.removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    result.setAttribute("disabled", "");
  }
  fCustomSelectUpdate(result);
});

result.addEventListener("change", () => {
  // Вывод результата
  console.clear(); console.log(`Адрес: ${toggleSel.value} ${result.value}`);
});

/* Закрытие неактивных списков */
function fCustomSelectClose(ev) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".sel-container.open").forEach((el) => el.classList.toggle("open", ev.target.closest(".sel-container.open") == el));
}
document.addEventListener("click", fCustomSelectClose);

/* Добавление обёртки */
function fCustomSelectInit(oSelect) {
  let width = getComputedStyle(oSelect).width;
  oSelect.style.display = "none";
  oSelect.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `
<div class="sel-container" style=" width: ${width};">
<a class="sel-single">${oSelect.value}</a>
<div class="sel-drop">
<div class="sel-search"><input autocomplete="off"></div>
<ul class="sel-results"></ul>
</div>
</div>
`);
  let oSelContainer = oSelect.nextElementSibling;
  let oSelSingle = oSelContainer.querySelector(".sel-single");
  let oSelSearch = oSelContainer.querySelector(".sel-search");
  let oSelSearchInput = oSelSearch.querySelector("input");
  let oSelResults = oSelContainer.querySelector(".sel-results");

  oSelSingle.addEventListener("click", function() {
    oSelContainer.classList.toggle("open");
  });
  oSelSearchInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    let rExp = new RegExp(`(?:\\s|^)${this.value}`, "gi");
    oSelResults.querySelectorAll("li").forEach((el) => el.classList.toggle("active-result", el.textContent.search(rExp) != -1));
  });
  oSelResults.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName != "LI") return false;
    oSelSingle.textContent = ev.target.textContent;
    oSelect.selectedIndex = ev.target.dataset.index;
    oSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
    oSelContainer.classList.toggle("open");
  });
}
document.querySelectorAll(".sel-group").forEach((el) => fCustomSelectInit(el));

/* Обновление пунктов в обёртке */
function fCustomSelectUpdate(oSelect) {
  let oSelContainer = oSelect.nextElementSibling;
  let oSelResults = oSelContainer.querySelector(".sel-results");
  oSelResults.innerHTML = "";
  oSelect.querySelectorAll("option").forEach((el, i) => {
    oSelResults.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<li class="active-result" data-index="${i}">${el.textContent}</li>`);
  });
  oSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
  oSelContainer.querySelector(".sel-single").textContent = oSelect.value;
}
fCustomSelectUpdate(toggleSel);
```

```css
body { display: flex; justify-content: center; }
legend { font: bold 14px serif; }

.sel-group { width: 200px; }

.sel-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 13px sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
}
.sel-group[disabled]+.sel-container {
  filter: contrast(50%) brightness(150%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sel-single {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0 25px 0 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444; background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, #fff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #fff inset, 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}
.open .sel-single {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to top, #fff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
}

.sel-single::after {
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 25px; width: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.open .sel-single::after { transform: scaley(-1); }

.sel-search {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 13px;
}
[data-search-input]+.sel-container .sel-search { display: block; }

.sel-search::after {
  content: "\1F50D";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 31px; width: 23px;
  line-height: 31px;
  color: #aaa;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sel-search input {
  height: 25px; width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sel-drop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa; border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(100% 100%);
  clip-path: inset(100% 100%);
}
.open .sel-drop {
  clip: auto;
  -webkit-clip-path: none;
  clip-path: none;
}

.sel-results {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  max-height: 240px;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  color: #444;
}

.sel-results li {
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px 6px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 15px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.sel-results li.active-result {
  display: list-item;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sel-results li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #53b2fc, #1385e5);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Выберите Ваш район</legend>
  <!-- Чтобы появилось поле поиска, добавьте атрибут "data-search-input" -->
  <select class="sel-group" id="toggleSel">
    <option>---</option>
    <option>р1</option>
    <option>р2</option>
    <option>р3</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Выберите Ваш город/посёлок</legend>
  <select class="sel-group" id="result" data-search-input disabled></select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Сейчас покажу, вот от сюда брал, там второй комментарий, код, через подключения chosen. https://javascript.ru/forum/css-html/69429-kak-sdelat-poisk-v-selekte.html Когда так делаю - первый селект нормально отображается, но второй переставал работать

Comment: @Oleja322: если время до утра терпит, то можно сделать без сторонних библиотек и с кодом по минимуму.

Comment: та конечно, буду благодарен, с массивом кстати тоже не сработало. Или мб скажите как это реализовать, попробую сделать.

Comment: @Oleja322: глянул я этот плагин... Много там всякого, но как я понял, ваша задача не требует никаких фишек. Куда и в каком формате выводить результат? Что ожидается на выходе?

Comment: потом от выбора города/посёлка должны менятся цены в таблице цен (тарифы)

Comment: @Oleja322: в общем, выведу в переменную и в консоль.

Comment: ого, днём буду разбирать, спасибо, отпишусь. это оно должно потом в консоль выводить выбор, а потом, грубо говоря, для таблиц тарифов - этот выбор забирать от туда нужно?

Comment: В общем круто, спасибо, ещё раз)